# Deserialization with gson when JSON no have variable names

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Json bellow:

```
{
    "0001":[111, "BLABLA", "LALA", "KKK",80,20],
    "002":[222, "BLABLA", "LALA", "KKK",80,40],
    "003":[333, "BLABLA", "LALA", "KKK",100,20],
    "000":[444, "BLABLA", "LALA", "KKK",800,60],
    "555":[555, "BLABLA", "LALA", "KKK",80,20,
    "100":[48, "BLABLA", "LALA", "KKK",80,20]
}
```

I'm having trouble with Gson deserialize. I know work with Json that have variable names defined as below:

```
{
   "item":"001":["id":1,"description":"bla bla"],
   "item":"002":["id":2,"description":"bla bla"]
}
```

Then I defined the class with the same variable names of the json and execute a parse

```
public class DataClass
{
  String item;
  int id;
  String description;

  getters and setters;

}

gson.fromJson (json, DataClass.class);
```

But I do not know how to do this in case I need to use the json without variable names (in the beginning of post). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This class answers your question:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q18116805;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q18116805 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json =                                                 
            "{  \"0001\":[111, \"BLABLA\", \"LALA\", \"KKK\",80,20],   "+
            "    \"002\":[222, \"BLABLA\", \"LALA\", \"KKK\",80,40],   "+
            "    \"003\":[333, \"BLABLA\", \"LALA\", \"KKK\",100,20],  "+
            "    \"000\":[444, \"BLABLA\", \"LALA\", \"KKK\",800,60],  "+
            "    \"555\":[555, \"BLABLA\", \"LALA\", \"KKK\",80,20],   "+
            "    \"100\":[48, \"BLABLA\", \"LALA\", \"KKK\",80,20]}";

        Type aType = new TypeToken<Map<String,ArrayList<Object>>>() {}.getType();
        Map<String,ArrayList<Object>> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, aType);

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

> {0001=[111.0, BLABLA, LALA, KKK, 80.0, 20.0], 002=[222.0, BLABLA,
>   LALA, KKK, 80.0, 40.0], 003=[333.0, BLABLA, LALA, KKK, 100.0, 20.0],
>   000=[444.0, BLABLA, LALA, KKK, 800.0, 60.0], 555=[555.0, BLABLA, LALA,
>   KKK, 80.0, 20.0], 100=[48.0, BLABLA, LALA, KKK, 80.0, 20.0]}

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a variable name to the string. `"\"name\":" + json` before deserializing.

Comment: Thanks, but the I can't change de Json.

Comment: Is `gson.fromJson ("\"name\":" + json, DataClass.class);` not sufficient?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I will receive the information into a string in the variable "name". I dont need of gson to do this, simply use the string directly.
I want to deserialize it into an object with defined attributes.